# implementing simple one-to-one and one-to-many relationship

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive, flutter-isar

i have this database schema for my application and i think this schema is correct but i can't add multiple item with one-to-many relationship, in the first time i can add one user with one group and config, but i can't add multiple group to one user and multiple config to one group

`User` can have many `Group` and each `Group` belongs to one `User`

`Group` can have many `Config` and each `Config` belongs to one `Group`

and i can have many `User` in application

`USER` collection:

```dart
@collection
class UserCollection {
  Id id = Isar.autoIncrement;
  late String username = '';
  late String password = '';
  final group = IsarLinks<GroupCollection>();
}
```

`GROUP` collection:

```dart
@collection
class GroupCollection {
  Id id = Isar.autoIncrement;

  final IsarLinks<ConfigCollection> config = IsarLinks<ConfigCollection>();

  @Backlink(to: 'group')
  final user = IsarLinks<UserCollection>();

  late String label;
}
```

`CONFIG` collection:

```dart
@collection
class ConfigCollection {
  Id id = Isar.autoIncrement;
  late String remark;

  late String link;

  @Backlink(to: 'config')
  final group = IsarLinks<GroupCollection>();
}
```

now i want to create new data into database

```dart
void testSaveDatabase() async{
  final isar = IsarHelper.instance;

  const link =
     "LINK";


  final newConfig = ConfigCollection()
    ..remark = 'test'
    ..link = link

  final newGroup = GroupCollection()
    ..label = 'label'
    ..config.add(newConfig);

  await isar.isarInstance.writeTxn(() async {
    try{
      final user = isar.findLast<UserCollection>();

      await isar.isarInstance.configCollections.put(newConfig);
      await isar.isarInstance.groupCollections.put(newGroup);

      user!.group.add(newGroup);
      newGroup.config.add(newConfig);

      await newGroup.config.save();
      await user.group.save();

    }catch(error){
      print(error);
    }
  });
}
```